# Measure space with range $[0,1] \cup [3, \infty]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let the space be $\mathbb R$ and the $\sigma$-algebra be $\mathcal P(R)$; define a measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal P(R))$ in the following way:

$\mu(\{x\}) = x$ if $x \ge 3$.

$\mu(\{n\}) = 2^{n}$ if $n$ is a negative integer.

$\mu(\{x\}) = 0$ for other values of $x$.

I think this defines a measure with range $[0,1] \cup [3, \infty]$. I am using what's on page 42 of Sheldon Axler's Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis which basically says that you can define a measure by defining its value on singleton sets (it's not stated as a theorem, so I am not sure if I have misunderstood anything). Am I correct?

Comment: Yes.  Summations can be viewed that way with each integer having measure 1.

Comment: You can use representation in base 2 to show that $[0,1]$ is actually contained in the image of $\mu$.

Comment: @Ramiro I am just concerned that $\mu$ might for some reason turn out not to be a measure.

Comment: Ok, but $\mu$ is a measure. I have posted an answer with two different proofs that $\mu$ is a measure. In my answer there is also a complete proof that the image of $\mu$ is $[0,1]  \cup [3,+\infty]$.

Comment: I have posted a detailed and **correct** answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: congrats on the correct definition; here is a related link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200648/for-which-c-in-3-infty-there-does-exist-a-measure-space-x-mathcals-mu/4208016#4208016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you defined $\mu$, it is a measure.

> Let $X$ be a set and let $f: X \rightarrow [0, +\infty)$ be a function. Let us define, for any $E \subseteq X$,
> $$\mu(E)= \sum_{x \in E} f(x)$$
> Then, $\mu$ is a measure defined on $\mathcal P(X)$.

**Proof 1** Clearly:

1. for all $E \in \mathcal P(X)$, $\mu(E) \geq 0$
2. $\mu(\emptyset)=0$
3. Let $\{E_n\}_n$ be a countable collection of pairwise disjoint set in $\mathcal P(X)$, then
   $$ \mu \left ( \bigcup_n E_n   \right )= \sum_{x \in \bigcup_n E_n} f(x) = \sum_n \sum_{x \in  E_n} f(x) = \sum_n  \mu(E_n) $$
   (middle equality is true because $f(x) \geq 0$ , for all $x$.) $\square$

**Proof 2**: Consider the measure space $(X, \mathcal P(X), \#)$, where $\#$ is the counting measure. Note that $f$ is a non-negative function which is measurable with respect to $\mathcal P(X)$. Note that, for all $E \in \mathcal P(X)$,
$$ \mu(E) = \int_E f d \# $$
So, $\mu$ is a measure. $\square$

In your case of your question, $X= \Bbb R$ and $f$ is the function defined as

$f(x) = x$ if $x \ge 3$.

$f(n) = 2^{n}$ if $n$ is a negative integer.

$f(x) = 0$ for other values of $x$.

---

It is easy to see that $\text{Image}(\mu) \subseteq [0,1] \cup [3, +\infty]$.
It is also easy to see that $[3, +\infty] \subseteq \text{Image}(\mu)$.

So, it remains to show that $[0,1] \subseteq \text{Image}(\mu)$.

Given any $x\in[0,1]$, $x$ can be written in base 2 as $0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$, where each $a_i$ is either $0$ or $1$. (Note that $1=0.11111\dots$).  It follows immediately that

$$ x = \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n 2^{-n} = \mu(\{-n : n\geq 1 \text{ and } a_n =1 \})$$

Hence $x \in \text{Image}(\mu)$ and so we have proved that $[0,1] \subseteq \text{Image}(\mu)$. $\square$

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is correct and detailed.

Answer (score 1):

That the range of $\mu$ is indeed $[0,1]\cup[3,\infty]$ is not difficult to check. clearly $\mu\geq0$. Now,

1. For any subset $A\subset\{0\}\cup(-\mathbb{N})$
   $$\mu(A)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{\mathbb{1}_{A}(-k)}{2^k}$$
   where $\mathbb{1}_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. To any number $x\in(0,1]$, consider its unique binary expansion $x=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{x_k}{2^k}$ where $x_k\in\{0,1\}$ with $\sum_kx_k=\infty$. Then you can see that by matching $\mathbb{1}_A(-k)$ with $x_k$ you can reconstruct the what $A$ should be.
2. $0=\mu(-\sqrt{2})$ for instance.

(1) and (2) cover all values in $[0,1]$

3. Any number  $y\in [3,\infty)$ are attained by $\mu$ by design: $y=\mu(\{y\})$.
4. $\mu(3\mathbb{N})=\sum^\infty_{n=0}3n=\infty$.

(3) and(4) takes care of $\mu$ taking any value in $[3,\infty)$.

---

The issue seems to be that you are not sure whether $\mu$ $\sigma$--additve in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

One possible way to look at this is to consider the following the counting measure $\#$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, that is, $\#(A)=n$ if $A$ has $n$ elements, and $\#(A)=\infty$ if $A$ is infinite elements.

- That this is a measure, it easy to check ($\#(\emptyset)=0$, and if $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are pairwise disjoint, then $\#(\bigcup_n A_n)=\sum_n\#(A_n)$. The latter is finite if each $A_n$ is finite and all but finitely many $A_n$ are empty).  Try to convince yourself that indeed the convince yourself this is indeed the case.

---

If you are  familiar with the concept of integral with respect to a measure, the recall that

$\color{blue}{\textrm{ If $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is a measure and $f\geq0$ is a measurable function, then}}$

$$\color{blue}{\mu_f(A):=\int_{A}f(x)\,\mu(dx)}$$

$\color{blue}{\textrm{ 
defines a measure on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$. This measure is sometimes denoted as $f\cdot\mu$.}}$

If you are well aware if this, consider
$$\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=x\mathbb{1}_{[3,\infty)}(x)\\
f_2(x)&=2^x\mathbb{1}_{-\mathbb{N}}(x)
\end{align}$$

The  set function $\mu$ in your OP is
$$\mu=(f_1\cdot\#) + (f_2\cdot\#)=(f_1+f_2)\cdot\#$$

---

If you are not familiar yet with integration, you then need to prove from scratch that $\mu_1(A)=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{\mathbb{1}_A(-k)}{2^k}$ and
$\mu_2(A)=\sum_{x\in A}x\mathbb{1}_{[3,\infty)}(x)$ are each measures. Once this is done, notice that $\mu=\mu_1+\mu_2$.

That $\mu_1$ is a measure is easy. I leave the details to you but notice that $\mu_1$ is closely related to the geometric distribution that one studies in probability.

The pesky issue is  $\mu_2$. Clearly $\mu_2(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu_s(A)\geq0$ for any set.

Only $\sigma$-addtivity requires a check. Suppose $\{A_n\}$ are pairwise disjoint sets.

- If all the $A_n$'s are in $(-\infty,3)$, then $\mu(A_n)=0$ and of course $\sum_n\mu_2(A_n)=0$.

  Now, suppose all $A_n$'s are contained in $[3,\infty)$.
- If one of them is infinite or neither of them is empty, then $\bigcup_nA_n$ is an infinite set and of curse $\infty=\mu_2(\bigcup_nA_n)$ and $\sum_n\mu_2(A_n)=\infty$.
- Suppose all $A_n$'s are finite,  that all but finitelly many, say $\{A_{n_1},\ldots A_{n_k}\}$, are empty, and that
  $A_{n_j}=\{x^j_1,\ldots, x^j_{m_j}\}$, $j=1,\ldots,k$. Then it is easy to check (remember, we are assuming that the $A_n$'s are pairwise disjoint
  $$
  \mu_2\Big(\bigcup_nA_n\Big)=\sum^{m_j}_{\ell=1}x^1_\ell+\ldots+\sum^{m_k}_{\ell=1}x^{k}_{\ell}=\sum^k_{j=1}\mu_2(A_{n_j})$$

Consequently, $\mu_2$ is indeed a measure.

---

Hope this helps