# For which $c\in [3,\infty)$ there does exist a measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ such that $\{\mu(E):E\in\mathcal{S}\}=[0,1]\cup[3,c]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to find out for which $c\in [3,\infty)$ there exists a measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ such that $\{\mu(E):E\in\mathcal{S}\}=[0,1]\cup[3,c]$.

My solution:

(**EDIT**  *my solution is wrong, as Calvin Khor pointed out in a comment below because one could take a set $E$ which has an overlapping of measure $1$ with $[0,1]$ and $[3,c]$ such as $[0,4]$ or an interval like $[3,4.5]$ which would then sum to a number greater than $1$ but smaller than $3$. In general, if such a measure existed for some $c>4$ then we would have that there exist $E_1, E_2\in\mathcal{S}$ such that $\mu(E_1)=3,\ 4<\mu(E_2)<4.5$ so $1<\mu(E_2)-\mu(E_1)<4.5-3=1. 5$ thus $1<\mu(E_2\setminus E_1)<4.5-3=1.5$, contradiction. So, the claim is true for $c=4$ (as shown in other answers) and cannot be true for $c>4$).*

Let $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\mu)$, where $\mu:\mathcal{B}\to [0,\infty]$ is the function $\mu(E):=|E\cap [0,1]|+|E\cap [3,c]|$, where $c\in\mathbb{R}, c\geq 3$ and $|\cdot|$ is the outer measure. Then, $\mu\Big(\emptyset\Big)=|\emptyset\cap [0,1]|+|\emptyset\cap [3,c]|=|\emptyset|+|\emptyset|=0+0=0$ and if $E_1,E_2,\dots$ are disjoint sets in $\mathcal{B}$ then $$\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k)=|\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\cap [0,1]|+|\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\cap [3,c]|=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|E_k\cap [0,1]|+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|E_k\cap [3,c]|=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Big( |E_k\cap [0,1]| + |E_k\cap [3,c]| \Big)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)$$ so $\mu$ is a measure and by the way it is built it gives us, as all the numbers in $[0,1]$ and $[3,c]$ for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is this correct? Are there others (perhaps simpler) solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Your $\mu$ doesn't work, because e.g. take $c=10$ then $\mu([0,4])=2$. One thing you could do, for $c=4$, is add $3\delta_0$ to Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933982/ This shows that you must have $c \geqslant 4$.

Comment: And the accepted answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171436/ shows that the only possibilities for $c \geqslant 4$ is $c = 4$ or $\infty$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani thanks for the references

Comment: @CalvinKhor thank you for your interest in my question; if you would post your comment as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting comment to answer on request of OP. I will also quickly give the full solution as in the links.

1. Your $\mu$
   doesn't work, because e.g. take $c=10$
   then $\mu([0,4])=2$.
2. For $c=4$, you can consider  $\mu = dx+3\delta_0$ where $dx$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.
3. Show that $c\ge 4$ as follows. As $\operatorname{range}\mu = [0,1]\cup [3,c]$, we see that $\mu(X)=c$, and there exist $A,B$ with $\mu(A)=3$ and $\mu(B)=1$. If $\mu(A\cap B)=0$ then $c=\mu(X) \ge \mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B) = 4$ as claimed. Otherwise, $\mu(A\cap B) \le \mu(B)=1$ and then $$3=\mu(A)> \mu(A\setminus (A\cap B))=\mu(A)-\mu(A\cap B) \ge 3-1 = 2,$$showing that $\mu(A\setminus (A\cap B)) \notin [0,1]\cup [3,c]$,  contradicting the assumption. (source: [first link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933982/))
4. Show that $c \le 4$ as follows. Suppose that $c>4$. If $c<5$ then choosing $E$ with $\mu(E)=3$, note that $\mu(X\setminus E)=c-3\in(1,2)$ which is contrary to assumption. If $c\ge 5$, then instead let $\mu(E)=c-2\ge 3$. Then $\mu(X\setminus E)=c-(c-2)=2$, which is again contrary to assumption. (variant of argument in [second link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171436) )
5. The above assumes $c\in\mathbb R$, but $c=\infty$ is also possible, e.g. $dx|_{[0,1]} + \mu$ where $dx|_{[0,1]}$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and $\mu(\{x\})=x$ for $x\ge 3$ and zero otherwise. (See second link.)

Comment: thank you for your interest in my question; regarding part 5 of your answer it seems to me that your proposed measure wouldn't work as $\mu([0,1])=2\notin [0,1]\cup [3,\infty]$ and not even $\mu:=dx|_{[0,1]}+3\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\delta_i$ as in this case $7.5\notin\{\mu(E):E\in\mathcal{B}\}$ (I am assuming $(X,\mathcal{S})=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}))$.

Comment: Oops. Thanks very much  for checking! I will edit to link to the older answer instead @lorenzo

Comment: another question, if I may: how can I define $\mu$ on all of $\mathcal{B}$ if I only know $\mu(E)$ when $E$ is a singleton?

Comment: @lorenzo The unwritten definition would be $$\mu(E):=\sum_{x\in E}\mu(\{x\}) := \sup_{F\subset E, \\ F\text{ finite}}\sum_{x\in F}\mu(\{x\})  $$